# JavaScript / jQuery scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Hi I'm extending an existing plugin to use static JSON rather than load it from the server.  This is a trimmed down version of the extension:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.MyExtension = function (options) {
        return this.each(function () {
            if (opts.load_Json) {
                $.get("", function (result) {
                    fromJson(opts.load_Json)
                });
            }

            var fromJson = function (json) {
                    // json stuff..
                 }  
        });
});
```

If I remove the `$.Get` and call `fromJson` directly without the call back I get an error saying that `fromJson` is not defined.  This must be some form of scope issue but I cant work it out?

Comment: You have `options`, and later `opts`. Is that really from your code, or just a question typo?

Comment: And if you move the `var fromJson = function (json) {}` assignment to above the conditional?

Comment: You code also defines a function but then throws it away, doing nothing with it and never running the code within it. Due respect, I recommend you create a [short, self-contained, **correct** example](http://sscce.org) and post that instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't scope. This is timing.

A function isn't assigned to `fromJson` until the end of the anonymous function you pass to `each`.

If you call it from your `get` callback, then that assignment will happen before the HTTP response comes back and the function fires.

If you call it directly, then it just doesn't exist yet.

Either reorder:

```
    return this.each(function () {
        var fromJson = function (json) {
                // json stuff..
             }  

        if (opts.load_Json) {
            $.get("", function (result) {
                fromJson(opts.load_Json)
            });
        }

    });
```

Or use a function *declaration* (which will be subject to hoisting):

```
    return this.each(function () {
        if (opts.load_Json) {
            $.get("", function (result) {
                fromJson(opts.load_Json)
            });
        }

        function fromJson (json) {
                // json stuff..
             }  
    });
```

Comment: Brilliant, nail on the head.